# How many solutions for $\,\sum_{k=1}^{n}p_k=p_m\cdot p_{m+1}\,$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

**I ask for which pairs $(m,n)$ is satisfied
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}p_k=p_m\cdot p_{m+1}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime.**

Up to $n=10^7$ I have found only the solution $(4,8)$ that is
$$2+3+5+7+11+13+17+19=7\cdot11$$
**Could it be the only solution of the equation $(1)$?**

Many thanks.

Comment: Could be, for sure you have that $(m,n)$ is not a solution if n is odd: this becouse for $p_m\cdot p_{m+1}$ to be even, you need $p_m =1$, so that $p_m\cdot p_{m+1}=p_1\cdot p_2 = 6$, which isn't any good for a solution, so the only solutions have $p_m\cdot p_{m+1}$ odd, so on the left hand side you need an odd number of odd primes with the $2$ at the beginning, so $n$ even.

Comment: What comes near is $n=2190$ giving $269\cdot 271^2$. If the last prime in the sum is less than $10^9$, there is no more solution. That means that there is no further solution for $n\le 50\ 847\ 534$

Comment: If $k$ starts from $2$ then $3 + 5 + 7 = 3 \times 5$.